# Get query string "group_id" into controller action and into new page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, model-binding

I am starting with the basics in .NET CORE 6 using EFCore and scaffolded Models.
I have Group, Ticket and Intervention. The controllers scaffolded into CRUD pages from the models. (CRUD pages work fine)

Created some groups in the create page and added a button for each group in the list with the id with href="/ticket/create?group_id=x" (x being the id of the group of the line) this way i can create a ticket attached to the group i clicked on.

My question is, how do i get the id from the query url into the ticket create page form so that the ticket i create is attached to that group.

In other words how do i add previous group "group_id" into the ticket model "group_id". This way the ticket is attached to that "group_id".

I started reading about Model Binding in the Microsoft Docs but can't find a proper tutorial or documentation to learn it.

If i'm doing this wrong then please point me into the right direction.

Should i go for Model Binding ?
Eventually... what path or tutorials should i follow to learn this properly.
Microsoft Doc is very inefficient.

My ticket Model:

```
  public class Ticket
{

    // [Key] - Primary Key - Not necessary when field is named "Id"
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int group_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int author_user_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int requester_user_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime creation_date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
    public string? description { get; set; } // ? - Nullable

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime closed_date { get; set; }


}
```

UPDATE 2022 06 09

I start with an index Group page where i have my list of groups for which i click "create ticket" in order to get my ticket attached to that group.

[image: Group Index Page with Create Ticket]

Then i want the query string "group_id" into my Ticket/Create page inside the form so that when i save the new ticket the previous group id is already in there.

I have tested with success the following code:

```
 // GET: Tickets/Create
    // WORKING HERE
    [HttpGet()]
    public string Create([FromQuery(Name = "Group_Id")] int previous_group_id)
    {          
        return previous_group_id.ToString();
    }
```

But i need somehing like this:

```
    // GET: Tickets/Create
    // WORKING HERE
    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Create([FromQuery(Name = "Group_Id")] int previous_group_id)
    {          
        return View();
    }
```

**How do i return the "previous_group_id" into the view and how do i call for it in the html page ?**

[image: HTML to display the previous_grouop_id in the ticket create page]

**UPDATED WITH CODE ANSWER - NOK**

[image]

Best regards
Rui Ruivo

Comment: It's hard to answer your question with the information provided. It seems like you could use a `[FromQuery]` parameter to capture the value from the query string and then have your controller action put that value onto the model that you render in your form. Then your form View can put that value into a hidden form field so when the form gets submitted it's included in the POST.

Comment: Perfect... can you please provide code examples for each step please ? Thats exactly what i want.

Comment: From your question, When you want to create Ticket in create page, There are different buttons representing different groups in that page, I think you can set an onclick method on these buttons, and  When user click the button, onlick method will add group id  to Ticket.

Comment: I have updated the question title for precision.  
StriplingWarrior got my problem right, what code should i use at each step please ?

Comment: In order for others to better understand your question, you should provide your page design.

Comment: Updated with more details

Answer (score 2):

TEST000

Now From your question, you have pass the id of group to controller successfully, Then you want to use the value of data in the view, You can follow the code:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create([FromQuery(Name = "Group_Id")] int previous_group_id)
    {          
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket()
        {
            group_id = previous_group_id
        };

        return View(ticket);
    }
```

Then in the View

```
@Model Ticket

//your view code

//use the tag helper(asp-for) to call the value, For Example, IF you want to use that value in <input/>

<input asp-for="@Model.group_id" class="xxxx"/>
```

Reter to this [ducoment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about `Tag Hepler` in Asp.Net Core

Comment: I apologise, i edited your answer. please disard my edit. Did not know it was a feature.

Comment: I love your answer but could not make it work, please check my update at the bottom of my question.

Comment: IT WORKS, Thank You, remove semicolon

Comment: I edited the code to put the semicolon where it belongs. @RuiRuivo if this answers your question be sure to mark it as the answer.